# Add new tab dynamically with bootstrap/twig

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, twig

I want to add remove tab dynamically with bootstrap in my twig i found a source code [Dynamically add/remove new tab](https://jeykeu.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/dynamically-add-remove-and-re-number-tabs-in-twitter-bootstrap/) but it dosen't work when i click on "Add tab" nothing happend can you help me please this is my twig :

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}

<script type="text/javascript" >

    $(doument).ready();

    var pageNum = 1;
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size()+1;

        $('<li><a href="#tab'+nextTab+'" data-toggle="tab">Tab '+nextTab+'</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

        $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab'+nextTab+'">tab' +nextTab+' content</div>').appendTo('.tab-content');

        $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
    });    
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size()+1;
        $('<li><a href="#tab'+nextTab+'" data-toggle="tab">Tab '+nextTab+'</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

        $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab'+nextTab+'">tab' +nextTab+' content</div>').appendTo('.tab-content');
        $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
    }); 
</script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}

{% block sonata_admin_content %}

<a href="javascript:;" id="btnAdd"><i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"></i> Add Tab</a>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs hidden-print" role="tablist" id="tabPanel">
   <li classe="active"><a id="tab_form" href="#formulaire" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Formulaire</a></li>
   <li><a id="tab_form" href="#formulaire" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tableau de bord</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

    <div class="tab-pane" id="formulaire">
        <div class="stats-content">
            <div class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
                {% include 'TechappStatsBundle:Stats:form.html.twig' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in a console?

Comment: no nothing with firebug

Comment: after refresh the page firebug tells that ReferenceError: doument is not defined
 

$(doument).ready();

Comment: It is right. You have a `$(doument).ready();` line while it should be `document`. Moreover, it is not a proper usage of `document ready`.

Comment: i understand but i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

in Add button click 
use this

```
var nextTab = $("#tabPanel li").length+1;
//Add tab button to ul
$("#tabPanel").append("<li><a href='#tab"+nextTab+"' data-toggle='tab'>tab"+nextTab+"</a></li>");

//Add Tab Content
$(".tab-content").append("<div id='tab"+nextTab+"' class='tab-pane'>tab"+
nextTab+"Content</div>");
```